# Where is the Django Migrations model?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I wish to make a custom model, which has a foreign key relationship to the django_migrations table.  Can this be done?  if so, exactly how do I import the django migrations model?

Edit...  Here is my plan

1: I have one database in which there are many tables on the 'Public' schema which are used for application-wide data. I suspect this system will get very large so for scalability I would like each of the clients to have their own schema.  These schema will be dynamically generated upon creation of a client

2: The client schema are controlled by a separate python/django app which has it's own set of tables/migrations.

3: I want the system to be flexible so that in the future, when new features are created, I can deploy those features to a few specific clients without having to deploy to everyone therefore each of the client schema may be at a different migration level, hence, there is a need to track which migration level each client is at

Comment: The `MigrationRecorder` class has it as a class property: [GitHub link to code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8d160f154f0240a423e83ffe0690e472f837373c/django/db/migrations/recorder.py#L25) Although I feel if you try to use that you will probably get weird errors since it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#dependencies) that "_Apps without migrations must not have relations to apps with migrations_" And the migration model obviously won't have a migration of its own. Out of curiosity what are you attempting to do?

Comment: I am trying to set up a system with dynamically created databases.  Each database will need to be migrated manually and so i would like to have my own table in each of those db's that points to the current migration level of that database

Comment: Have you seen [django-tenants](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in that case? It seems to do what you are trying to do (With the database specifically being PostgreSQL).

Comment: I have not, but this looks promising, thanks.